# Difference between wiki pages library and pages library?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have the following scenario.

We have a sharepoint 2010 web template to create sites in our organization.\ After the site is created there is a custom button that activates publishing features.

The strange thing is that when I do this, and I create new wiki pages, they are located in the pages library instead of the wiki pages library.

I would like to know what is the difference from the behavior point of view between those 2 libraries?

I wonder if we activate publishing features in the web template from the beginning it would work differently?

The problem is that our webtemplate is based on the blank template. So when we activate wiki feautures on a site, it adds the wiki pages to the pages library instead of the wiki pages library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is a configuration issue. When you have the publishing features enabled from the start it knows where put the pages, when you enable the publishing features after it doesn't know where put the wiki pages and put these in the standard library